# C# remove a string between 2 characters from the last

Tags: c#

string str = "www.website.com/thisfolder/secondfolder/folder/lastone/";
I want to remove all strings from the last between slashes "/"

Like I want on First button press "lastone/" Should be removed
            On Second Button Press "folder/" should be removed
            on third button press "secondfolder" should be removed

```
 these sub strings are not constant and it should continue
```

Comment: Please update post to include what youv'e tried, what's not working and a test case.

Answer (score 0):

Split original str by '/' character. Then, keep all splitted items except last one:

```
 string[] splitted = str.split("/");
 str = "";
 for (int i = 0; i < splitted.length - 2; i++)
 {
      str += splitted + "/";
 }
```

Comment: Problems: if it terminates in a "/" it will return the same string BUT more importantly  
You are basically removing all the "/" from the rest of the string

Comment: Yep, fixed that

Comment: you've still not fixed the fact that if it terminates in a / it'll basically return the same string

Comment: After the split, array will be something like: {"www.website.com", "thisfolder", "secondfolder", "folder", "lastone", ""}. In the for I'm not getting the last 2 items, right?

Comment: ok yes but waht if it doesn't terminate with a /?  if you just  do StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries it covers both cases

Answer (score 0):

This would work:

```
var path = //some path;
//remove empty entries otherwise if the string terminates in \ you'll get an empty string at the end of the array
var bits = path.Split('/', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var str = string.Join("/",bits.Take(bits.Length-1));
```

You'd need to do more with error checking though.